# How to create Wordpress posts from external json file?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

Here is the code I am using. It creates duplicate post every time I refresh. Also, how can I add custom field to my post?

My array looks like this:

```
[{
    "featured":"",
    "exclusive":"",
    "promo_id":"XXX",
    "offer_id":"1",
    "title" : "Super Cars"
}]
```

My php code:

```
<?php 
$json = "url";
$response = file_get_contents($json);
$mydecode = json_decode($response);

for ($i = 10; $i < 15; $i++) {
    $title = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $mydecode[$i]->title);
    $id = $mydecode[$i]->offer_id;
    $link = $mydecode[$i]->link;

    if( $id === "x" ) {

        $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $description,
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'coupon'
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    }
}
?>
```

The code successfully inserts posts but duplicate every time I refresh.
If anyone can contribute a bit, it would be great!

Comment: You need to check post by `title` using query.

Comment: Ok but how ? thank you for replying

Comment: Check this post : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58593/check-if-post-title-exists-insert-post-if-doesnt-add-incremental-to-meta-if

Comment: Yes, it works. thank you @hardiksolanki , but now how can i insert custom fields and assign custom taxonomies to my post.

Comment: You can add custom field using ` add_post_meta($post_id, 'your-custom-filed', '1');`

Comment: I tried but its not happening. i used add_post_meta($post_id, 'clpr_coupon_code', $coupon_code) and also update_post_meta($post_id, 'clpr_coupon_code', $coupon_code) but its not working. Where do i insert it ?

Comment: Make sure you have used proper `field`.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to following,

```
<?php
$json = "http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=xxxxxxxxxx";
$response = file_get_contents($json);
$mydecode = json_decode($response);

for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
    $title = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $mydecode[$i]->coupon_title);
    $description = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $mydecode[$i]->coupon_description);
    $store_name = $mydecode[$i]->offer_name;
    $coupon_type = $mydecode[$i]->coupon_type;
    $coupon_code = $mydecode[$i]->coupon_code;
    $link = $mydecode[$i]->link;
    $expiry_date = $mydecode[$i]->coupon_expiry;
    if( $coupon_type === "Coupon" ) {
        // Check if already exists
        $get_page = get_page_by_title( $title );
        if ($get_page == NULL){
            // Insert post
            $new_post = array(
                'post_title' => $title,
                'post_content' => $description,
                'post_status' => 'draft',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_type' => 'coupon'
            );
            // Insert post
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
            // Insert post meta if available  
            add_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', 'meta_value' );  

            // Uncomment to check if meta key is added
            // $get_meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', true );        
            // echo "<pre>";
            // print_r($get_meta_value);
        }
    }else{
        // Update meta value
        update_post_meta($get_page->ID, 'my_key', 'meta_value');

        // Uncomment to check if meta key is added
        // $get_meta_value = get_post_meta( $get_page->ID, 'meta_key', true );        
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($get_meta_value);
    }
}
?>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Its working already but still not able to retrieve 'meta_key'. how can i find that ?

Comment: Now i am able to do it. Thanks :)

Comment: How can i select the custom taxonomy and assign to the post ?

Comment: Read this: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/create-custom-taxonomies-wordpress/

Comment: Well that didn't help but I was able to do it. Thank you anyways.